# Memory Issues with long list in Ember array controller

Tags: javascript, memory-management, ember.js

I am using Ember array controller to list data. When we have more then 100 records. On desktop it's fine but on mobile it's not working smooth. So i google and found this link

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/view-rendering-performance-ember-v-angular/1897

It says "We dived into the Ember rendering pipeline and noted that it is based on string concatenation . As a collection view enumerates its children, it generates a string representation of each child view and appends them to the buffer of the collection view. The string buffer is then converted into to a document fragment before appending itself to the DOM."

Kindly suggest. What will be the better way to implement list view in ember.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Ember.ListView](http://emberjs.com/list-view/). It looks like it might have some issues on iOS, but it seems to be the current consensus for rendering a large list efficiently.

See also:

- [Is ListView appropriate for an app with a growing number of resources?](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/is-listview-appropriate-for-an-app-with-a-growing-number-resources/2727)
- [An introduction to Ember.ListView (youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3vEjbjV8Sk)